# Is it possible to change the speed at which a wheel is freely spinning by moving only its axle?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity, gyroscopes, precession

Suppose we have a wheel spinning on a perfectly lubricated axle. Is it possible to change its angular velocity about that axle, by moving only the axle?

1. Due to the wheel's symmetry about the axle's axis, I presume that translational motion of the axle can have no impact on its angular velocity about the axle.
2. Due to the fact that no torque parallel to the axle can be exerted on the wheel, I want to presume that the component of its angular momentum parallel to the axle is conserved, and therefore that its angular velocity about the axle remains constant. I therefrom want to conclude that changing the axle's axis requires exerting whatever torques will cause the wheel to keep spinning at the same rate about the axle's changing axis. But I don't feel sure that this reasoning holds up.

Comment: Possibly irrelevant, but rotating the axle by $180^{\circ}$ would completely reverse the direction of the rotation, thus 'changing' the angular velocity from positive to negative depending on the definition of coordinates.

Comment: @Shrek Yes indeed. In the sense I mean the word "speed", that doesn't count as change. i.e. If we know that it would reverse exactly, that would be confirmatory for what I want to believe.